# auth failed - mongodb - pymongo - k8s

Tags: python, mongodb, yaml, pymongo

I'm trying to connect into mongodb with pymongo, but i can't import data or create a collection.

This is the code to connect into mongo :

```
db_local = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local:27017", username="admin", password="pass")

mydb_local= db_local["test"]
```

And then i tried this to create new collection :

```
mydb_local.create_collection("HDFS"]
```

While trying to add the collection i get this error :

**Authentification failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': Authentification failed.', 'code : 18, 'codeName': AuthentificationFailed'}**

Meanwhile, i deployed Mongodb into Minikube, and this is the mongodb-sercret.yaml file :

```
apiVersion : v1
kind: Secret 
metadata: 
    name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data : 
     mongo-root-username : dXNlcm5hbWU=
     mongo-root-password : cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease try this :

```
db_local= pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://admin:pass@mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local:27017")
```

Comment: same error it's not working :/